# #1054 - La columna 'pieza.codigo_componente' en where clause es desconocida

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy ejecutando esta sentencia:

```
select descripcion FROM componente
where 
componente.codigo = pieza.codigo_componente AND
pieza.codigo = pieza_equipo.codigo_pieza AND
pieza_equipo.codigo_equipo = equipos.codigo AND
equipos.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

Me salta este error:

> ## 1054 - La columna 'pieza.codigo_componente' en where clause es desconocida

La estructura de mis tablas es la siguiente:

```
create table componente (
    codigo int not null,
    familia varchar(30) not null,
    descripcion varchar(30) not null,
    stock int not null,
    marca varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (codigo),
)

create table pieza (
    codigo int not null,
    codigo_componente int not null,
    descripcion varchar(30) not null,
    SN int not null,
    proveedor varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (codigo),
    index codigo_componente(codigo_componente),
    foreing key (codigo_componente) reference componente(codigo));
)

create table pieza_equipo (
    codigo_pieza int not null,
    codigo_equipo int not null,
    primary key (codigo_pieza),
    primary key (codigo_equipo),
    index codigo_pieza(codigo_pieza),
    foreing key codigo_pieza reference pieza(codigo));
    index codigo_equipo codigo_equipo 
    foreing key codigo_equipo reference equipo(codigo));
)

create table equipo (
    codigo int not null,
    descripcion varchar(30) not null,
    primary key (codigo),
)
```

No soy capaz de encontrar el error.... :(

gracias de antemano!

Comment: No se que tratas de hacer con esa sentencia, pero creo que lo que buscas es un JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que en el `FROM` de tu sentencia no tienes declarado la tabla `pieza`, aunque esa tabla exista en tu `DB` no estas haciendo referencia a ella en la consulta. Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT componente.descripcion 
FROM componente, pieza, pieza_equipo, equipos
WHERE componente.codigo = pieza.codigo_componente AND
pieza.codigo = pieza_equipo.codigo_pieza AND
pieza_equipo.codigo_equipo = equipos.codigo AND
equipos.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

Declaras en el `FROM` todas las tablas que vas a relacionar para que no te siga marcando el error. Al igual para no escribir todo el nombre de la tabla puedes utilizar un alias para identificar la tabla, quedando tu consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT comp.descripcion 
FROM componente AS comp, pieza AS pza, pieza_equipo AS pzaequip, equipos AS equip
WHERE comp.codigo = pza.codigo_componente AND
pza.codigo = pzaequip.codigo_pieza AND
pzaequip.codigo_equipo = equip.codigo AND
equip.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes especificar tu base de datos al comienzo de tu query:

```
 USE DATABASE
 SELECT descripcion FROM componente
 WHERE componente.codigo = pieza.codigo_componente 
 AND pieza.codigo = pieza_equipo.codigo_pieza 
 AND pieza_equipo.codigo_equipo = equipos.codigo 
 AND equipos.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

O especificas la base datos en tu FROM (en el llamado a las tabla):

```
 SELECT descripcion FROM DATABASE.componente C
 WHERE C.codigo = pieza.codigo_componente 
 AND pieza.codigo = pieza_equipo.codigo_pieza 
 AND pieza_equipo.codigo_equipo = equipos.codigo 
 AND equipos.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tratabas de hacer es un SELECT con varios JOIN para referenciar correctamente las tablas

```
SELECT descripcion FROM componente
INNER JOIN pieza
ON componente.codigo = pieza.codigo_componente 
INNER JOIN pieza_equipo
ON pieza_equipo.codigo_pieza = pieza.codigo
INNER JOIN equipo
ON pieza_equipo.codigo_equipo = equipo.codigo
WHERE 
equipo.codigo = 'EQ_1101'
```

Ojo que la tabla equipo es en singular, y también tenías referencias a una tabla equipos (plural)